# Fast way to insert 50 million records in Redis

Tags: c#, redis

I have a text file that is around 10 GB, containing 50 million lines. For each line that is in the file, I'm inserting the record if it doesn't already exist, otherwise do a comparison against the existing record's ID and the current line ID, and update if the current ID is less than the record ID.

Currently, it would take around 8 hours to insert/compare the records

Example data in text file:

```
Md5,Id
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e,1000
e358efa489f58062f10dd7316b65649e,1001
626726e60bd1215f36719a308a25b798,1002
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e,5002
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e,0953
626726e60bd1215f36719a308a25b798,0152
```

I've tried implementing producer/consumer pattern but the producer would be too fast and consume a lot of memory, resulting in an OutOfMemory exception.

```
ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost");

            IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();
            int lineCount = 0;
            foreach(var f in File.ReadLines(@"big_text_file.txt").Skip(1))
            {
                lineCount++;
                string[] lines = null;

                lines = f.Split(",")


                if (!db.KeyExists(lines[2]))
                {
                    db.StringSet(lines[2], lines[0]);
                }else //contains key
                {
                    var keypair = db.StringGet(lines[2]);
                    if(Convert.ToInt32(lines[0]) < Convert.ToInt32(keypair))
                    {
                        db.StringSet(lines[2], lines[0]);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Could you keep the keys in memory instead of checking against the database for every record? Could you do the check and insert in two separate threads?

Comment: If i store just the key in memory using Hashset, I will eventually get an outofmemory error.

Comment: Well, 50M times an MD5 hash with a bit of extra is about 2GB. This should not be the enemy. I believe an ordered list is better for storing the keys. Maybe you have to implement your own binary search.

Answer (score 6):

You code has several problem, you can optimize them to make it run much faster.

#### Too many request to Redis.

If the key doesn't exist, for each record, you send 2 requests to Redis. If the key already exist, for each record, you send 3 requests to Redis. So for 50 million records, you send 100 - 150 million request to Redis. There will be lots of round trip time. So it will be very slow.

Instead, you can wrap your code into a [Lua script](https://redis.io/commands/eval), and for each record, only send request to Redis once.

Also, you code is NOT atomic. If there're more than one client send request to Redis, your code breaks. However, with Lua scripting, you can make sure the code is atomic, so that you can do the seconds optimization.

#### Increase concurrency

It seems that you send request to Redis with a single thread/process. Redis is very fast, however, your client is too slow. So you can split your records into several parts. For each part, create a new thread to send request to Redis. Of course, you must make sure your code is thread-safe, check the first optimization.

#### Decrease the number of records

From your example, your records have many duplicate MD5, and different Id. So many requests to Redis is a no-op, since they will be overwritten by subsequent requests. So you can do a (external) sort, and remove these duplications before sending requests to Redis.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `redis-cli --pipe` command.

First you create a file with all SET commands and save it as `data.txt`:

```
SET Key0 Value0
SET Key1 Value1
...
SET KeyN ValueN
```

Then you can run the `redis-cli --pipe` command

```
cat data.txt | redis-cli --pipe
```

For detailed info see [Redis Mass Insertation](https://redis.io/topics/mass-insert)